# remove the dot after the year with natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I want to have a citation that is listed as follows:

Meier, Max ~~~     2009 ~~~   My first paper.

Where ~~~ stands for a TAB.

I am using natbib and I found a way to change the space between Max and 2009, but I did not find a way for getting rid of the dot after 2009, which is normally inserted. Can this be done with natbib or do I have to do this in the bst file?

Added MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{SM.bib}
  @misc{a, author={Max Meier}, title={My first paper}, year=2009}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}


\setcitestyle{
notesep={: }, % 2002: 125
aysep={~}     % Gazdar 2002
}


\bibliographystyle{degruyter-hsk} 

\bibliography{SM}
\end{document}
```

De Gruyter .bst is here: [degruyter-hsk.bst](http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/transfer/degruyter-hsk.bst)

Comment: What bibliographystyle are you using?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your requirements can be achieved be editing the `bst` file. Instead of the dot what do you want to get? A comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be done in the style file, where you can repeat the "ugly hack" on function `date.block`. Replace

```
FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  new.block
}
```

with

```
FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  before.all 'output.state := 
  "\hspace{1em}" output add.blank
}
```

[image: sample output]

But, oh my, this looks *so* wrong.

Comment: You last sentence should be bold.

Answer (score 2):

As mafp already answered, you must change this in style file (*.bst).

Search for:

```
FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  new.block
}
```

But do not change it in what mafp suggested. It gives you ugly empty spaces. Instead change it to:

```
FUNCTION {date.block}
    {
      skip$
    }
```

This will give you identical style but without dot after year.